# Best way to save nested JSON to Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have setup my code to call and parse JSON using a struct called "Recipe" using Decodable. What would be the best way to save some of these recipes to core data? Should I have one entity named "recipe" with every variable being an attribute? Or, should I have multiple entities, such as "recipe", "recipe_details" and "ingredient" etc.

```
struct Recipe: Decodable {
    var recipe: Recipe_details
    var bookmarked: Bool
    var bought: Bool
}

struct Recipe_details: Decodable{
    var uri: String
    var label: String
    var image: String
    var source: String
    var url: String
    var shareAs: String
    var yield: Float
    var dietLabels: [String]
    var healthLabels: [String]
    var cautions: [String]
    var ingredientLines: [String]
    var ingredients: [Ingredient]
    var calories: Float
    var totalWeight: Float
    var totalTime: Float
}

struct Ingredient: Decodable {
    var text: String
    var weight: Float
}
```

Comment: How do you go from JSON to Core Data?

Comment: You need to create an entity for each of your struct models. and define an entity-relationship to link the data.
Check out documentation for more details on how to do this:- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html

Comment: See if this helps - https://github.com/3lvis/Sync